# How to insall laravel/ui pacakge on Laravel 7.8.1

Tags: php, laravel, web, encoding, frameworks

I have try to install by typing the command "composer require laravel/ui" . But it doesn,t give any response. It just stuck and i waited for 1 hour but no errors or success is showing.Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your machine?

Comment: yes i have tried this too but no effect at all. It not even giving error or some. it just stuck and not doing anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

include laravel/ui package manually with the version inside the composer.json file and run a composer install

example:

"laravel/ui ": "^2.0"

Comment: how to add manually ? i don,t anything about laravel and these things. can u explain a little bit ?

Comment: yes, take a look at your composer.json file
There will be a field called required like the image on this link https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/symfony-composer-json-example.png
add "laravel/ui ": "^2.0" just like the packages included in the image